# How to use word Embeddings matrix of labels output to get better results for hierarchical image classification problem in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, word-embedding, multilabel-classification

optimize image classifier based hierarchical multi-label classification is the problem statement.

Assuming this Image classifier model whose output has 1X13 dimension `Dense` output layer `(None, 13)` Shape.
These labels are related in terms of a word-embedding matrix of shape `(13,100)` where 13 corresponds to each element in the label and 100 is the embedding dimension encoding the word features. I think we can increase the accuracy of the Image classifier model by using

Code for case 1:

```
def build_model (img_input , load_previous_weights = True, freeze_base = False):
    input_x = Input(shape = (img_input.shape[1:]), name='feature')

    base_model = MobileNet(include_top= False, input_shape=img_input.shape[1:], weights='imagenet')(input_x)
    if freeze_base:
            base_model.trainable = False

    # add a global spatial average pooling layer
    avgpool_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model)
    
    # Add a flattern layer 
    dense1_x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(avgpool_x)
    batch1_x = BatchNormalization()(dense1_x)
    dropout1_x = Dropout(0.2)(batch1_x)
    
    # Add a fully-connected layer
    dense2_x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(dropout1_x)
    batch2_x = BatchNormalization()(dense2_x)
    dropout2_x = Dropout(0.2)(batch2_x)
    predictions = Dense(13, activation='relu')(dropout2_x)
    ## -- I'll be adding 3 layers as mentioned below over hear to create new model
    # this is the model we will train
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs= input_x, outputs = predictions)
    # compile the model 
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= MERTICS)
    model.summary()
    return model
```

This is my Image Classifier summary

```
Model: "functional_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
feature (InputLayer)         [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenet_1.00_128 (Function (None, 4, 4, 1024)        3228864   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2048)              2099200   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 2048)              8192      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 512)               1049088   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 13)                6669      
=================================================================
Total params: 6,394,061
Trainable params: 6,367,053
Non-trainable params: 27,008
```

Is there any way to use this embedded matrix of 13X100 in order to encode the hierarchical nature of labels and thus to enhance the output result?
Please provide your insights and ideas.

This is one of such attempts, not sure whether something like this is allowed.
layers added to the `prediction` layer

```
###---- same thing repeated as above----
embedd_layer = Embedding(13, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False,name = "embedding_1")(predictions)
flatten = Flatten(name="flatten")(embedd_layer)
final_predictions = Dense(13, activation='relu')(flatten)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs= input_x, outputs = final_predictions)
# compile the model 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= MERTICS)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "functional_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
feature (InputLayer)         [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenet_1.00_128 (Model)   (None, 4, 4, 1024)        3228864   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_7 ( (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)             (None, 2048)              2099200   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (Batc (None, 2048)              8192      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_14 (Dropout)         (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_36 (Dense)             (None, 512)               1049088   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_37 (Dense)             (None, 13)                6669      
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 13, 100)           1300      
_________________________________________________________________
flat1 (Flatten)              (None, 1300)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_38 (Dense)             (None, 13)                16913     
=================================================================
Total params: 6,412,274
Trainable params: 6,383,966
Non-trainable params: 28,308
_________________________________________________________________
```

Where I have inserted a word embedding layer with pre-loaded embedded_matrix `shape = (13,100)` which I have mentioned above.
Will this approach works to increase accuracy of the model preserving knowledge matrix of labels?
Or is there any better approach?

Comment: Please switch the above summary with the minimum code that creates this graph, that way I can see the connection between the layers and also run it.  I'm assuming functional_block_1 is a tensorflow_hub image model, but if it is something else, please elaborate.

Comment: Hello.. I have updated the question as you have requested. I have added the model function and also the layers which I have inserted in the second case. I hope this clears any confusion you had to answer my question. Thankyou.

Comment: Are the 13 labels always the same like in classic image classification, or are you somehow using the 100 dim text-embedding to dynamically ask for a novel combo of 13 words?

Comment: 13 Labels are fixed. Always the same. I'm thinking of adding Word Embedding layer to address hierarchical nature of 13 Labels. The problem is Multi-label classification & thus my intuition is if somehow If I incorporate Embedding knowledge into traditional Multi-label Image classification, It'll give better results.